# Why is updating form erasing fields in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a form called bill with different bill names on it. The form is setup so that if no bill is present there is a placeholder but if a bill is present it shows that bills name. Form looks like this

```
bill.html.erb

<%= form_for [:users, @bill], :validate => true do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
      <% if bill.cell_phone.blank?  %>
        <label> Cell Phone Company Name</label>
          <%= f.text_field :cell_phone, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter your cell phone company name as it shows on your bank statement" %>
     <% else %>
       <label>Current Cell Phone Company Name:</label>
          <%= bill.cell_phone %>
            <%= f.text_field :cell_phone, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Update your cell phone company name as it shows on your bank statement" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
<div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
      <% if bill.gas_name.blank?  %>
        <label> Heating Gas Company Name</label>
          <%= f.text_field :gas_name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter your heating gas company name as it shows on your bank statement" %>
      <% else %>
          <label> Current Heating Gas Company Name:</label>
            <%= bill.gas_name %>
            <%= f.text_field :gas_name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Update your heating gas company name as it shows on your bank statement" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

My problem is for some reason if I change one of the bills and try to update it erases the other bills and only updates the new bill. I want to be able to update one bill and keep the others. Even though on my server log it shows all bills going into the update. Here is the log...

```
Started PATCH "/users/bills/...400000a" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-09-08 17:57:38 +0000
Processing by Users::BillsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xlzypBl1o3+iqAMROYUnjAuTR3TUIgSzyIA4EaVRkMw=", "bill"=>{"cell_phone"=>"Virgin", "gas_name"=>"nicor", "rent_name"=>"wells fargo", "electric_bill"=>"comed", "water_bill"=>"city of chicago", "cable_bill"=>"direc tv", "insurance"=>"american family", "current_rent_pmt"=>"1325"}, "commit"=>"Update Bill Payments", "id"=>"...400000a"}
D, [2015-09-08T17:57:38.851608 #11316] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} runtime: 0.9856ms
D, [2015-09-08T17:57:38.853790 #11316] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=sample_development collection=users selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('...1000000')}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 2.0296ms
D, [2015-09-08T17:57:38.856265 #11316] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=sample_development collection=bills selector={"$query"=>{"tenant_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('...1000000')}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.6492ms
D, [2015-09-08T17:57:38.860914 #11316] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=sample_development collection=bills selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('...400000a')} update={"$set"=>{"cell_phone"=>"virgin", "gas_name"=>nil, "rent_name"=>nil, "electric_bill"=>nil, "water_bill"=>nil, "cable_bill"=>nil, "insurance"=>nil}} flags=[]
D, [2015-09-08T17:57:38.861626 #11316] DEBUG -- :                          COMMAND      database=sample_development command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 0.9025ms
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/dashboard
Completed 302 Found in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Finally, here is my bills_controller update method (which seems to work fine)

```
def update
    @user = current_user
    if current_user.bill.update_attributes(bill_params)
      TransAggregationWorker.perform_async(@user.id.to_s)
      redirect_to users_dashboard_path, :notice => "Payment Informaton Updated"
    else
      redirect_to users_dashboard_path, :notice => "Payment Information was not updated, please try again"
    end
  end
```

-UPDATE-

Here is the bill params

```
def bill_params
    params.require(:bill).permit( :cell_phone, :gas_name, :rent_name, :electric_bill, :water_bill, :cable_bill, :insurance, :current_rent_pmt)
  end
```

Comment: "it erases the other bills" -- do you mean other bills on the same user? Using `current_user.bill` indicates there's only one bill for each user. Or does `User` `has_many :bills` and the line should be `current_user.bills`?

Comment: Yes there is 1 bill per user. In other words 1 bill model containing multiple bill name fields. And if you look at the console I put in the question it shows the user sending the bill with old and new info to the server but on about the 3rd or 4th line it only shows 1 or 2 items which are the items that were updated. But it should keep the old items that were not updated

Comment: So what's the relation? User `has_one :bill`? Also you didn't answer about your statement "it erases the other bills" -- what "other bills"? do you mean other bills on the same user?

Comment: The relation is has_one :bill and to answer the question it replaces the other field names with nil if they werent put back in to the form. So for example if there are 3 fields in the user specific bill model and there inputs are "A,B,C" The form will show "A, and B and C" are already in the model. If I update the model with replacing "C" with "D" then it will update but the fields where "A and B" were at will now be nil and C will just be replaced with "D".

Comment: Ah I see, and I see it in the SQL `UPDATE`. Can you post your controller's `bill_params` method?